# Download video from URL and share it on Facebook, Messages, Twitter using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using `Alamofire` for networking and working with `Swift 4`.

I need to download a video from URL and store it in a particular location and then share it using `UIActivityViewController` on `Facebook`, `Messages`, `Twitter` etc.

Can someone provide some sample code or guide me on this?

Regards!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to download video using Alamofire

```
func downloadVideo() {
    let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination()
    let url = "https://lynda_files2-a.akamaihd.net/secure/courses/391599/VBR_MP4h264_main_SD/391599_00_01_WX30_welcome.mp4?c3.ri=3770828196132302975&hashval=1522966719_0c357049da0562665ab3f99ccd3e8bca"

    Alamofire.download(url, to: destination).downloadProgress(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)) { (progress) in
        print("Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
    } .validate().responseData { [weak self] (response)  in
        self?.shareVideo(from: response.destinationURL!)
    }
}
```

and share using UIActivityViewController

```
func shareVideo(from url: URL) {
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
    present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jaba ,I will check it tomorrow and let u know

Comment: Thanks works great.
Just one more thing where does it get downloaded. Will I have to manually clear this ?

Comment: You can use cache directory to save temporary data. system will delete when it will be nesessary. change destionation like this let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

Comment: Solved my problem. Also added a method on app launch to clear cache. Thanks mate :)